# How to handle consumer execution error in SQS + Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I configured SQS + Lambda and everything works fine. I am making some simulations and sending messages that create errors. When I do this, the message stays in flight forever and the lambda stays executing. How is the best way to not let this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, that setup is working as expected. To prevent what are you describing you have to configure a DLQ SQS and setup your primary queue. 
Take a look at DLQ SQS.

Ref:https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-dead-letter-queues.html

Steps:

1. Just create a new queue (like: **nameOfYourPrimaryQueueDLQ**);
2. Then r-click on your primary SQS and select **Configure Queue**.
3. Find **Dead Letter Queue Settings** label, check the **Use Redrive Policy**, put a **Maximum Number Receives** and finally set the *ARN* of your new SQS queue (which you created recently) to **Dead Letter Queue**.

It going to work like that:

1. You are sending a message to SQS queue;
2. Then the SQS going to trigger your Lambda function;
3. If it failed, then SQS will try to send another event-message to your lambda until you hit a maximum number receives and after that the current message will be sent to SQS DLQ.